# Angular5-Toaster Dynamic component inject parameters

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-toastr

I am trying to create a dynamic template to display information from a dynamic component as listed in the NPM readme.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular5-toaster

Example:

```
import {BodyOutputType} from 'angular5-toaster';

@Component({
  selector: 'dynamic-component',
  template: `<div>loaded via component</div>`
})
class DynamicComponent { }

var toast : Toast = {
    type: 'error',
    title: 'Title text',
    body: DynamicComponent,
    bodyOutputType: BodyOutputType.Component
};
      
this.toasterService.pop(toast);
```

My question is how would I pass parameters into the DynamicComponent.

Comment: why can't you set the value in to a service before loading the component? Once component initialize you can read the value

Comment: Really good idea i have no idea why i didn't think of it before.

Comment: Thanks..I would suggest this solution. Also one more way by creating instance of the component but not recommended. You can go with this approach.

Comment: I have added this solution as an answer , If it's works you can mark it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to share the data using Angular Service.

**Step 1 :** 
set the data want to pass in to the dynamic component before you load the Toast.

```
    this.someService.data="some parameter"
    this.toasterService.pop(toast);
```

**Step 2 :** 
Once the component initialize you can read the value by injecting the service as a dependency on your dynamic component.

```
ngOnInit(){
//read the data
console.log(this.someService.data)
}
```